# Can't upgrade from 5.26.* to 5.28.*

Tags: drupal, extension, upgrade, drush, cv

We got 2 demo websites that we are using publicly to show translations. When I tried to update them, they returned from drush command the following:

```
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.19 sec, 7.5 MB]                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.19 sec, 7.93 MB]                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 4 (max=5) [0.19 sec, 7.93 MB]                                                                                                       [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.19 sec, 7.93 MB]                                                                                          [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.16-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.39 sec, 24.5 MB]                                                                       [debug]
Find command files for phase 5 (max=5) [0.39 sec, 24.5 MB]                                                                                                       [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.16-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.39 sec, 24.5 MB]                                                                       [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.16-commandfiles-5-98c00c316acff50d31c7b21c6455733c [0.39 sec, 24.52 MB]                                                                       [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.16-annotationfiles-5-fc9c7995bc64309247ba8dcb0f2a811a [0.4 sec, 25.24 MB]                                                                     [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.43 sec, 26.98 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.43 sec, 26.98 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 6 (max=6) [0.44 sec, 25.69 MB]                                                                                                      [debug]
Found command: civicrm-upgrade-db (commandfile=civicrm) [0.44 sec, 25.69 MB]                                                                                 [bootstrap]
Cache MISS cid: 8.1.16-alias-path--cae21634989c45f52c3c725c39d2002e [0.46 sec, 27.45 MB]                                                                         [debug]
Calling hook drush_civicrm_upgrade_db_validate [0.76 sec, 29.52 MB]                                                                                              [debug]
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. [1.01 sec, 37.66 MB]                                                                      [error]
```

CV command returns as if its not working. Tested on few websites it is working. Latest version is installed. Output is bellow:

```
 cv upgrade:db


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryClass()


upgrade:db [--out OUT] [--dry-run] [--retry] [--skip] [--level LEVEL] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER]
```

On another website that has CRM 5.20 version, CV runs smoothly. I've been trying to install to newest one, 5.28.3 but sadly it didn't work. So I did backtracking, managed to install up to 5.26.3 version. After trying to install 5.27.0 it returned same kind of errors as for 5.28.3 , website is not responsive, cant access database or Drupal front end. Drush isn't working, CV as well.

CiviCRM log is empty, PHP showed something... and got to resolution of my issues. Mikey told me to keep it as proof for others if they encounter issues so there is that. Answer for my trick question in comments!

Answer (score 5):

Issue causing this:
Extensions.

In PHP logs I found out Symphony was mentioned along with Flexmailer. We had alpha outdated version of Flexmailer causing issues. Disabling it/ updating it seems to work as solution.

After that I could update CiviCRM smoothly and works!

Hopefully someone will need this in the future!